# access 2010 connection with java

Tags: java, ms-access, 64-bit, database-connection, dsn

i have written a class [as shown by most tutorials] to make connection to an Access 2010 database

```
    package dataBase;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    public class connection 
    {
         static Connection conn;
         ResultSet res;
         Statement stat;

         public Connection makeConn() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
         {
             Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:TestDriver:sampleDb");
             return conn;
         }

         public void closeconn() throws SQLException
         {
             conn.close();
         }

          public void Search() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
          {
              stat=conn.createStatement();
              res=stat.executeQuery("select * from table");
              while(res.next())
              {
                  System.out.println(res.getString("id"));
              }
          }
    }
```

here **TestDriver** = User DSN Microsoft Access Driver
**sampleDb** = Microsoft Access Db that is located on my desktop

my access 2010 is 64 bit, i m running it on 64 bit machine, and my environment is eclipse galileo

when i try to run it i get the following error

```
  plug in started
  java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at dataBase.connection.makeConn(connection.java:18)
at newmodulewizrd.ui.App.<init>(App.java:32)
at archetypedcomponent.commands.newModuleHandler.execute(newModuleHandler.java:39)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:770)
at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$10(CommandContributionItem.java:756)
at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:746)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3910)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3503)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1287)
```

**what m i doing wrong?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110697/establishing-connection-from-java-to-access-2010-64bit

this is the new type of problem that i m facing