# Establishing connection from java to access 2010 64bit

Tags: java, ms-access, database-connection, jdbc-odbc, file-not-found

After going through several tutorials and blog posts, i have unsuccessfully tried to set up a connection from java to a microsoft access database. my system specifications are

> win 7 [64 bit]  odbcad32.ese [64 bit]  access 2010 [64 bit]  jre6 [64
>   bit]

the **code** that i wrote for establishing a connection :

```
        public Connection makeConn() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
        {
           Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\ARIFAH\\Desktop\\sampleDb.mdb");

           return conn;
        }
```

in the **data source** [odbc]---[located at path **%windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe**]

i performed the following task

1. **USER DSN TAB**  ADD->Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb ) [file ACEODBC.dll] ->Finish
2. **Data Source Name**: TestDriver ; **Description**: test driver for access 2010 64 bit ;
3. **DataBase**->select ->browse: C:\Users\ARIFAH\Desktop\sampleDb.mdb -> ok
4. apply
5. ok

now when i try to run my application, this is the **error** that i m getting,

```
    java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file '(unknown)'.
            at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at dataBase.connection.makeConn(connection.java:22)
        at newmodulewizrd.ui.App.<init>(App.java:32)
        at archetypedcomponent.commands.newModuleHandler.execute(newModuleHandler.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
        at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:770)
        at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$10(CommandContributionItem.java:756)
        at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:746)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3910)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3503)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1287)
```

**Can somebody help with it?**

Comment: i have now changed my "32 bit galileo eclipse" to "64 bit helos eclipse"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing your connection string to:

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\ARIFAH\\Desktop\\sampleDb.mdb
```

That appears to be the difference between the 32 and 64 bit versions of the driver.  I am able to connect using that string with the same environment.

(Now I just have to figure out what's happening with the "java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length" error I'm getting...)

Answer (score 0):

According to this blog, you either have to run 32-bit version of Java, or use 64-bit version of office drivers:

http://www.selikoff.net/2011/07/26/connecting-to-ms-access-file-via-jdbc-in-64-bit-java/